# why don't we use "beV" in the sentence with 'find'

Tags: participles, past-vs-past-perfect

We can say

> He came out and found his car stolen.

Why don't we say

> He came out and found his car **was** stolen.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what do you mean by "beV"?

Comment: @NikhilMehta A conjugation of the verb *be*. i.e. ***be, am, is, was, were, being, been,*** etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this sentence is not the usage of **be** together with **found**, but the exact meaning of **stolen**. If we replace **stolen** with **dirty**, we get a perfectly sensible sentence.

> He came out and found that his car was dirty.

This means that we walked outside, looked at his car and discovered that it was covered with dirt. **dirty** is an adjective describing this state. With stolen, he came out and found that his car wasn't there any more: he couldn't directly observe its state in the same way that he could when he saw that it was dirty.

So, instead of using describing the state of the car, we describe something that has happened to it. Somebody stole it: we don't know who, so we use passive voice and say **it has been stolen**. Because this must have taken place sometime before he came out, we use past perfect, **it had been stolen**.

> He came out and found that his car had been stolen.

Comment: thank u  btw  is the first sentence wrong ??

Comment: @Louis: it's a bit quirky but grammatically correct. If you look at this http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/find you will see that find can be used with a that-clause, as in my sentence, or it can be used with object + adjective: this matches "car stolen". Another example might be "he finds life difficult".